# How do I find out which replays go up to a certain level?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I'm looking for an old replay that I would like to show to my friends, but I can't find the one. I'm interested specifically in the replay where I reached the Necrodancer boss level, but I don't know which one that is. The game only shows the date of the replay's start, but not the score or up to what level I got. When I looked inside the replay files I found some hints that might indicate the level number. What exact text should I look for when looking for replays that go up to a certain level?